# SPOJ INVCNT - how?

Tags: c++, algorithm, fenwick-tree

can anyone help me with this task http://www.spoj.com/problems/INVCNT/ . First I try to think in BIT-way but I can't. Can anyone explain the solution of this task with BIT. BIT- Binary indexed tree 
c++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you know how to solve the following problem in `O(log n)` per query and update using a BIT:

```
Given an array A[1 .. n], implement the following functions efficiently:
query(x, y) = return A[x] + A[x+1] + ... + A[y]
update(x, v) = set A[x] = v
```

You can solve your current problem like this: first, normalize your array values. This means that you must transform all of your values such that they are in the interval `[1, n]`. You can do this with a sort. For example, `5, 2, 8` will become `2, 1, 3`. (Note: 1, 2, 3 are indexes in the sorted order of 5, 2, 8)

Then, for each `i`, we will answer how many inversions `A[i]` generates with elements `j < i`. For this, we need to find the number of elements before `i` that are larger than `i`. This is equivalent to `query(A[i] + 1, n)`.

After this query, we do `update(A[i], 1)`.

Here's how this works: our BIT array will initially be filled with zeros. A 1 at position `k` in this array means that we have encountered the value `k` in our iterating over the given array. By calling `query(A[i] + 1, n)`, we find how many inversions `A[i]` generates with elements before it, because we query how many elements larger than it we have iterated over so far.

After finding this, we need to mark `A[i]` as visited. We do this by updating the position `A[i]` in our BIT array and putting a 1 at it: `update(A[i], 1)`.

Since the numbers in the array are distinct from `1` to `n`, your BIT array has size `n` and the complexities are logarithmic in `n`.

Write if you want details on how to solve the initial problem, although it is a classic and you should be able to easily find code on Google.

**Note:** the problem also has a nifty solution using [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that you might want to think about.

Comment: Can you little bit more explain second part, with query(A[i]+1,n);

Comment: @Dario - it's pretty hard to follow your code. You could write a simple `O(n^2)` solution and compare the output of that with the output of the BIT solution on small test cases, then debug from there. Do you have a test case that it fails on?